# ¿Cómo abrir un archivo con el puro nombre sin tener que poner su extensión con python?

Tags: python

buen día. Espero estén muy bien.
Tengo un problema que no he podido resolver.
Intento hacer una aplicación con python en la que al especificar la ubicación del archivo (C:\Users\Cristhian-1\Archivo.558), no tenga que poner la extensión del archivo, algo así (C:\Users\Cristhian-1\Archivo.'*'), Se que se puede con comandos CMD (xcopy \192.168.1.33\Cristhian-2\ACTUEL\Archivo.*), y lo que espero puedan ayudarme si es que se puede hacer en python, ya que el archivo cambia la extensión por cierto lapso de tiempo.

Aquí un poco del código que llevo.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import numpy as np
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import image, ImageTk
import pandas as pd
import re
from humanize import naturalsize

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("575x390+675+350")
ventana.resizable(False, False)

#VARIABLES
nombre=StringVar

#FUNCIONES
def buscar():
    fichero=("archivo.557")#Aquí el problema archivo.'*', la extensión cambia en lapsos de tiempo.
    archivo0=Label(ventana,text=""+fichero+"").place(x=457,y=232)
    size=os.stat("archivo.557")#Aquí el problema archivo.'*'
    with open (fichero) as archivo:
        contador={}
        for linea in archivo:
            palabras = linea.split()
            for palabra in palabras:
                if palabras not in contador:
                    contador[palabra]=1
    archivo.close()
    for palabra in sorted(contador, key=contador.get,reverse=True):
        if palabra == nombre.get():
            palabra=Label(ventana,text="" + palabra + "").place(x=100,y=233)
#FRAMES
palabra=LabelFrame(ventana,text="",width=255,height=35)
palabra.place(x=85,y=230)
archivo=LabelFrame(ventana,text="",width=115,height=35)
archivo.place(x=450,y=225)
#ETIQUETAS
lbl_escribe=Label(ventana,text="Palabra:").place(x=10,y=40)
lbl_palabra=Label(ventana,text="Palabra:").place(x=10,y=232)
lbl_archivo=Label(ventana,text="Archivo:").place(x=387,y=230)
#CUADRO DE ENTRADA
entrada=Entry(ventana,extvariable=nombre).place(x=85,y=10,width=395,height=100)
#BOTON
boton_buscar=Button(ventana,text="Buscar",command=buscar)
boton_buscar.place(x=495,y=17)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Por favor, corrige la indentación de tu código para poder reproducir tu ejemplo. En python eso es fundamental.

Comment: ¿Hay más archivos en el mismo directorio con el mismo nombre, pero diferentes extensiones?

Comment: Es bastante fácil hacerlo si no hay más archivo con el mismo nombre, puedes hacer `archivo = [file for file in os.list_dir(os.getcwd()) if file=="archivo"][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sencilla es usando el modulo integrado **glob** el cual busca archivos usando patrones. Ver [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Suponiendo que existen estos archivos:

```
C:\Users\Cristhian-1\
|- Archivo.ext1
|- Archivo.ext2
|- File001.ext2
|- File002.ext5
```

Se puede hacer búsquedas de nombres de archivo y el patrón `*` después del mismo:

```
>>> import glob
>>> src_path = "C:\Users\Cristhian-1"
>>> glob.glob(src_path + "\\Archivo")
[]
>>> glob.glob(src_path + "\\Archivo*") # <- Esto es lo que necesitas
['C:\\Users\\Cristhian-1\\Archivo.ext1', 'C:\\Users\\Cristhian-1\\Archivo.ext2']
>>>
>>> # También se puede usar la forma NO documentada `glob1`
>>> glob.glob1(src_path, "Archivo*") # <- Esto es lo que necesitas
['Archivo.ext1', 'Archivo.ext2']
>>> # Otros ejemplos: 
>>> glob.glob1(src_path, "*.ext2") # Archivos con extension ext2
['Archivo.ext2', 'File001.ext2']
>>> glob.glob1(src_path, "*.ext*") # Archivos con extensión ext*
['Archivo.ext1', 'Archivo.ext2', 'File001.ext2', 'File002.ext5']
```

Comment: Hola. Como verán soy nuevo en esta pagina. Solo quiero agradecer a las personas que me apoyaron con sus cometarios, en especial a nuestro amigo aeportugal, me fue de mucha utilidad la información. Gracias!